# Дублирование 7 символов после ключевого слова

Tags: excel, текст

Есть столбец с 1000 строк в xlsx
Ячейки содержат в себе описание товара с html разметкой.
Необходимо найти текст src=[рандомные 7 цифр] - и дублировать эти самые 7 цифр рядом.

На выходе должен быть еще точно такой же столбец только ссылки там будут уже не как в исходном

```
src=[1234567]
```

а так:

```
src=[1234567_1234567]
```

Ссылок там в ячейке html описания несколько сотен. а ячеек в столбец - почти тысяча

Пример:
было >>>

```
описание ...<img alt="Перейти в" src="[image_id:1621172952]"
```

стало >>>

```
описание ...<img alt="Перейти в" src="[image_id:1621172952_1621172952]"
```

Огромное человеческое Спасибо за внимание!

Comment: >> *Ссылок там в ячейке html описания несколько сотен* - Значит ли это, что в одной ячейке нужно дублировать не одно, а несколько [сотен] значений? Количество символов в ID (разрядность числа) одинакова или может меняться? Дублировать всегда числовое значение?

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. 
Совершенно верно, в каждой десяток (иногда сотен) разных значений в такого вида src ссылках
Количество цифр неизменно, 
значение всегда только цифровое.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Загружаем данные в массив `aData`. В цикле (`For i`) проходим по текстам. Текст разбиваем на фразы по фрагменту-разделителю (`sSeparator`), записав фразы в массив `aSpl`. Последовательно (во внутреннем цикле `For j`) соединяем фразы, добавляя перед каждой (кроме первой) фрагмент из начала фразы (длина фрагмента задается константой `lLenID`). Выгружаем отредактированные данные на место исходных.

```
Sub RepeatID()
    Dim aData(), aSpl
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Const sSeparator As String = "image_id:" ' текст перед ID '
    Const lLenID As Long = 10 ' количество символов ID '
    
    With ActiveSheet ' Worksheets("sheet1") '
        i = .UsedRange.Rows.Count + .UsedRange.Row - 1
        aData = .Range("A1:A" & i).Value
      
        For i = 1 To UBound(aData)
            If aData(i, 1) <> Empty Then
                aSpl = Split(aData(i, 1), sSeparator)
                sTemp = aSpl(0) & sSeparator
            
                For j = 1 To UBound(aSpl)
                    sTemp = sTemp & Left$(aSpl(j), lLenID) & "_" & aSpl(j) & sSeparator
                Next j
            
                aData(i, 1) = sTemp
            End If
        Next i
        
        .Range("A1").Resize(UBound(aData), UBound(aData, 2)).Value = aData
    End With
End Sub
```

В примере работа ведется на активном листе, столбец с данными для редактирования - столбец *А*.

Код разместить в общем модуле.

Comment: Восхитительно! Моё почтение, всё заработало наилучшим образом. Просто создал макрос и всё поехало. Я попытаюсь поблагодарить Вас за проделанную Вами работу. Ищу возможный способ